# When I respond to HTTP request with `Range: 0-1023`, should I include `Vary: Range` in response?

Tags: http, http-headers, rfc

When the HTTP request contains header `Range` and the server responds `206 Partial Content`, should the response **always** include `Vary: Range`? I think because the output will be obviously different for any different Range but I cannot find any official requirement for this.

The `Vary` seems reduntant here because any user agent supporting partial content should implicitly understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "Vary" response field is needed here. HTTP Range Requests are not a form of content negotiation as specified.

Comment: Can you point to an RFC that defines this?

Comment: I don't believe it's explicitly stated. You may want to have a look at and potentially open a ticket on Github to get this clarified in the next set of specs.